# How to change large sections of HTML without using "innerHTML"

Tags: javascript, html, css

Here is an example of what I have:

```html
<body>

Pick a food:
<select class="food">
  <option value="pizza"> Pizza </option>
  <option value="Hamburger"> Hamburger </option>
</select>

<br>


<h1>If answer is pizza:</h1>

<div class="pizza">
  Select 2 toppings: <select name="topp1">
    <option value="pepperoni"> Pepperoni  </option>
    <option value="mushroom"> Mushroom </option>
    <option value="bell"> Bell Pepper </option>
  </select>

  <select name="topp2">
    <option value="mushroom"> Mushroom </option>
    <option value="pepperoni"> Pepperoni </option>
    <option value="bell"> Bell Pepper </option>
  </select>
</div>


<h1>If answer is Hamburger:</h1>


<div class="hamburger">
  Select 2 fillings: <select name="fill1">
    <option value="lettuce"> Lettuce </option>
    <option value="tomato"> Tomato </option>
    <option value="bacon"> Bacon </option>
  </select>

  <select name="fill2">
    <option value="tomato"> Tomato </option>
    <option value="lettuce"> Lettuce </option>
    <option value="bacon"> Bacon </option>
  </select>
</div>

<body>
```

What I want to do is have the `.pizza` div show whenever `"pizza"` is the value of `.food` and have the same happen for the `.hamburger` div.

I know it's possible to do this by setting the `innerHTML` of a single div in JavaScript, but that gets really tedious when you have more content you want to change. I've also tried the CSS `visibility` property, but that only makes one of the div's invisible and keeps the other one where it is.

As you can probably guess by now, I'm asking for a way to easily exchange multiple div's at a single point on the page.

Comment: Use `display: none` instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use classes to manage the show/hide and an event listener to listen for the change to the select menu

```js
window.addEventListener('load', () => {
  document.querySelector('.food').addEventListener('change', e => {
    // first hide all food-item selectors
    document.querySelectorAll(`.food-item`).forEach(el => el.classList.add('hide'));
    // now reveal the one we want to show based on the e.target.value
    document.querySelector(`.${e.target.value}`).classList.remove('hide')
  })
})
```

```css
.hide {
  display: none;
}

.food-item {
  margin-top: 20px;
}
```

```html
Pick a food:
<select class="food">
  <option value="pizza"> Pizza </option>
  <option value="hamburger"> Hamburger </option>
</select>
<div class="pizza hide food-item">
  Select 2 toppings:
  <select name="topp1">
    <option value="pepperoni"> Pepperoni </option>
    <option value="mushroom"> Mushroom </option>
    <option value="bell"> Bell Pepper </option>
  </select>
  <select name="topp2">
    <option value="mushroom"> Mushroom </option>
    <option value="pepperoni"> Pepperoni </option>
    <option value="bell"> Bell Pepper </option>
  </select>
</div>
<div class="hamburger hide food-item">
  Select 2 fillings:
  <select name="fill1">
    <option value="lettuce"> Lettuce </option>
    <option value="tomato"> Tomato </option>
    <option value="bacon"> Bacon </option>
  </select>
  <select name="fill2">
    <option value="tomato"> Tomato </option>
    <option value="lettuce"> Lettuce </option>
    <option value="bacon"> Bacon </option>
  </select>
</div>
```